# Matlab opening same file from different folders and not overwriting each other

Tags: matlab

I'm pretty new to Matlab, and I'm looking for possibly a way to open a file call `data.txt` from several subfolders of 2414A,2443A,6732A,4577A... and so on, without overwriting on top of each other. All of them are in one giant folder, just within different subfolders.

My question is, instead of changing the folder name every time I open the `data.txt`and setting a variable for each of the txt file, is there a quicker way to do so? Because my end goal is to concatenate all of the `data.txt` matrcies for computation.

I currently just have:

```
cd C:\User\Aisk_000\Desktop\A\NC\Subjects\2414A\
NC1 = dlmread('data.txt');
cd ../2443A\
NC2 = dlmread('data.xt');
cd ../6732A\
```

...etc. It definitely serves the job, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
files = dir('C:\User\Aisk_000\Desktop\A\NC\Subjects\*\data.txt');
files_num = numel(files);
files_data = cell(files_num,1);

for i = 1:files_num
    file = files(i);
    file_path = fullfile(file.folder,file.name);

    files_data{i} = dlmread(file_path);
end
```

If you want to build up a simple indexing system, use this code instead:

```
files = dir('C:\Users\Zarathos\Desktop\*\data.txt');
files_num = numel(files);
files_data = cell(files_num,2);

for i = 1:files_num
    file = files(i);

    file_folder_idx = strsplit(file.folder,'\');
    file_folder_idx = file_folder_idx{end};

    file_path = fullfile(file.folder,file.name);

    files_data{i,1} = file_folder_idx;
    files_data{i,2} = dlmread(file_path);
end
```

So if you have to save your files back to disk after they have been modified, you will be able to rebuild the structure of your `C:\User\Aisk_000\Desktop\A\NC\Subjects\` folder and know in which path you have to save the file data currently being processed.